# Finding less than 10% revenue accounts in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to find out less than 10% in revenue accounts from a table. Below is a table snapshot. Basically, I want to add Revenue mix column in the table.

```
ACCOUTS REVENUE REVENUEMIX
ACCOUNT1    100     2%
ACCOUNT2    200     4%
ACCOUNT3    500     9%
ACCOUNT4    1000    19%
ACCOUNT5    1500    28%
ACCOUNT6    2000    38%
TOTAL 5300  100%
```

Comment: If you are doing this in a stored procedure, or multi-statement script, you can populate a variable with the total revenue, and then the RevenueMix is a simple calculation of Revenue / @TotalRevenue.

Comment: do you want to get  2%,4%,19% record from the above table which is less than 10%???

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to populate Revenuemix column in the table.

Comment: Sorry if I'm unable to explain it better. I need to be able to take accounts that sum to 10% in revenuemix in ascending order based on each sales rep. Below is my current output. I need first need 19 columns for each sales rep from the table

Comment: Frankly, this sounds like a different question. You could try to edit the current query to use `PARTITION BY` and get the results that you want

Comment: My apologies @Lamak. Actually, you were right. This is kind of a second question from the existing one. I have 10 sales executives, each one has 20 accounts whose revenue is in ascending order from $100 each. I want to be able to sum those 20 accounts for each sales rep and calculate <=10% revenuemix, so that first set of accounts that sum upto 10% can be pushed into a new table and the loop continues till it reaches all the 10 sales reps. I hope this is clear. :(

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @P INT;
SET @P = 10;

WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  ACCOUNTS,
            REVENUE,
            CAST(REVENUE AS DECIMAL(5,0))/(SUM(REVENUE) OVER())*100 REVENUEMIX
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE REVENUEMIX < @P;
```

[**Here is a**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8a250/1) sqlfiddle with a demo of it. And the results that I get for your sample data are:

```
╔══════════╦═════════╦═════════════╗
║ ACCOUNTS ║ REVENUE ║ REVENUEMIX  ║
╠══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╣
║ ACCOUNT1 ║     100 ║ 1.886792452 ║
║ ACCOUNT2 ║     200 ║ 3.773584905 ║
║ ACCOUNT3 ║     500 ║ 9.433962264 ║
╚══════════╩═════════╩═════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `REPLACE() and CAST()`

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/856a9/2)

```
SELECT *
FROM tab_1 where cast(Replace(REVENUEMIX,'%','') as decimal(10,4))<10
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading the question correctly, you want to include the RevenueMix column that you showed in your example table to a table that contains just the Account and Revenue?  Something like this should work:

```
create table #table (
    account nvarchar(10),
    revenue int
    )

insert #table values
('ACCOUNT1',    100    ),
('ACCOUNT2',    200    ),
('ACCOUNT3',    500    ),
('ACCOUNT4',    1000   ),
('ACCOUNT5',    1500   ),
('ACCOUNT6',    2000    )

declare @TotalRevenue int
declare @MinimumRevenueMix numeric(8,2) = 10.0
select @TotalRevenue = SUM(Revenue) from #table

select  a.account,
        a.revenue,
        convert(nvarchar(20), a.RevenueMix) + '%' RevenueMix
    from (
        select  account,
                revenue,
                convert(numeric(8,2), convert(float, revenue) / convert(float, @TotalRevenue)) * 100 RevenueMix
            from #table
        ) a
    where
        a.RevenueMix < @MinimumRevenueMix

drop table #table
```

Comment: I like Lamak's answer... I was unaware of SUM(REVENUE) OVER(); very handy.

Comment: Can we go one step further and put a cap revenuemix at 10. So, when my revenuemix reaches 10% the next correspoding row should start with 0 from another account. In other words, I want to pickup only those accounts whose sum of revenuemix is less than or equal to 10% into a new table. Is it possible?